# Passing variables to function using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I have a text input field with its own class: `.my_ids`.  I'm trying to write a script with jquery so that every time the input changes, it calls a particular function.  This is easy enough if I don't try to pass a variable to the function:

```
$(document).on('change','.my_ids', testfunc);
function testfunc(){
    alert("good");
}
```

The function sends me an alert every time the input changes; works just fine.

**However** if I try to pass a variable to the alert function like so:

```
$(document).on('change','.my_ids', testfunc("hereismyvariable"));
function testfunc(myvariable){
    alert(myvariable);
}
```

it sends the alert when the document loads and then doesn't alert when the input changes.  What might I be missing?

Comment: Event handlers are attached as a reference to the function, but with brackets you invoked the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this

```
$(document).on('change','.my_ids', function() {
  testfunc("hereismyvariable");
});
```

Or you could do this

```
$(document).on('change','.my_ids', testfunc("hereismyvariable"));

function testfunc(myvariable){
  return function() {
    alert(myvariable);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are passing a function: 
`$(document).on('change','.my_ids', testfunc);`

Here you are passing the return value of a function: `$(document).on('change','.my_ids', testfunc("hereismyvariable"));`

Because `testfunc("hereismyvariable") = undefined`(No return value), you add an event handler with an undefined function.

Answer (score 1):

`()` operator call the functions, so the returned value of the function is set as the handler, which doesn't seem to be what you want. Other answers suggest several solutions. Another option is using the `data` argument:

```
$(document).on('change', '.my_ids', "hereismyvariable", testfunc);

function testfunc(event) {
    console.log(event.data); // "hereismyvariable"
}
```

The `data` argument can be anything. `data` property of the `event` object refers to the passed value.